# Showing $P$ is a linear operator on $\ell^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Lets say I have defined the operator
$$P:\ell^2 \to \ell^2$$
by
$$(Pa_n)=\bigg(\frac{1}{2} \bigg)^n a_n,$$
for $a=(a_n) \in \ell^2$.

> How do I show that $P$ is a linear operator on $\ell^2$?

Do we just show that $P(x+y) =P(x)+P(y)$
and $P(\alpha x)=\alpha Px$ ?

> How do I show that $P$ is a bounded linear operator on $\ell^2$?
>
> How do I determine $\|P\|$ which is the operator norm of $P$?

Comment: Always go back to the definitions, and check  the list of requirements one at a time, to see whether they are all met. This is often easier than you may expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is how you show that $P$ is linear.

To show it is bounded, let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $\ell^2$. Then,
$$\|P(a_n)\|^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n^2}{2^{2n}}\le\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2=\frac{1}{4}\|(a_n)\|^2,$$
so $P$ is a bounded operator of bound at most $\sqrt{1/4}=1/2$.

To show that $\|P\|=1/2$ consider the sequences
$$a_n=\frac{1}{2^{mn}}$$
for $m\in\Bbb N$. Then,
$$\|P(a_n)\|^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{(2m+2)n}}=\frac{1}{2^{2 m+2}-1},\quad\|a_n\|^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2mn}}=\frac{1}{2^{2 m}-1},$$
so
$$\frac{\|P(a_n)\|^2}{\|a_n\|^2}=\frac{2^{2 m}-1}{2^{2 m+2}-1}=\frac{1-2^{-2m}}{4-2^{-2m}}$$
and this goes to $1/4$ as $m\to\infty$. Thus, $\|P\|^2=1/4$ and hence $\|P\|=1/2$.

Comment: this is not a complete proof that $\|P\| = 1$. You only proved $\|P\|\leq 1$.

Comment: @user26977 Right.

Comment: @user26977 Edited.

Comment: @spenser just to clarify, when I am trying to show that P is a linear operator, I just substitute values for x and y in place of n?

Comment: @spenser why are we trying to show that $||p|| =\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @Aljabra Your third question asks to find the specific value of $\|p\|$. I am showing that this value is $1/2$.

Comment: @spenser thank you.how would you show if a operator is invertibe or not?

Comment: @spenser how did you get $\frac{a^ 2 _n}{2^{2n}}$?

Comment: @Aljabra By the definition of the $\ell^2$ norm.

Comment: What definition is that? Do you mind showing that in the answer please?

Comment: @Aljabra For a sequence $(b_n)\in\ell^2$, its norm is $\|(b_n)\|^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n^2$. Now substitute $(b_n)=P(a_n)=(a_n/2^n)$.

Comment: @spenser then you get $\bigg(\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^n a_n \bigg)^2$ dont you?

Comment: @Aljabra Yes, $\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^na_n\right)^2=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}a_n^2=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}a_n^2=\frac{a_n^2}{2^{2n}}$.